# One column is not created

Tags: android, sqlite

Can you guys see anything wrong with a db table creation statement?

```
CREATE TABLE userdata(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,title TEXT, login TEXT, password TEXT, notes TEXT, favorite INTEGER DEFAULT 0);
```

I use this String to create a db table:

```
public static final String CREATE_DATABASE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME
            + "(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + COLUMN_NAME_TITLE + " TEXT, "
            + COLUMN_NAME_LOGIN + " TEXT, " + COLUMN_NAME_PASSWORD + " TEXT, " + COLUMN_NAME_NOTES
            + " TEXT, " + COLUMN_NAME_FAV + " INTEGER DEFAULT 0);";

db.execSQL(CREATE_DATABASE);
```

But after all I don't have the latest (COLUMN_NAME_FAV) column in a table, I don't understand why. Here how I check:

```
c.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_NAME_FAV);
```

returns me `-1`, meaning theres is no such a column.

Comment: Have you checked the database table on the db directly?

Comment: question is how you're getting this Cursor c ... next question is are you running  "CREATE .." code in SQLHelper? if so did you run this code early on this device but with different create statment? in that case onCreate method of SQLHelper is not called again and you have to clear data for this app or uninstall app and install it again ...

Comment: I would love to, but it's kind of impossible in Android, or I don't know how...

Comment: It's a clean install. I got Cursor with a CursorAdapter, the Cursor is fine for the rest of data/columns.

Comment: Show us the SQL query which you are using to obtain the cursor. Are you actually trying to SELECT from this column in your query?

Comment: @GrahamBorland, yes, the SQL query is wrong, thank a lot: public Cursor getAll() {
        return (getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT _id, " + COLUMN_NAME_TITLE + ", "
                + COLUMN_NAME_LOGIN + ", " + COLUMN_NAME_PASSWORD + ", " + COLUMN_NAME_NOTES
                + " FROM " + TABLE_NAME, null));
    }

Comment: @GrahamBorland, please set the answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The column is only present in your Cursor if you have included that column in your `SELECT` query from which the Cursor is obtained.

Make sure your query includes something like

```
SELECT favorite, .... FROM userdata
```